# parametric circle in 3D?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Suppose I have two distinct unit vectors $P_0$ and $P_1$ both $
\in R^3$, such that $P_0 . P_1 = 0$, ie they are at right angles to each other.

I want a function $f$ that takes a real number and returns a unit vector such that

$f(0) = P_0$

$f(1) = P_1$

$f(2) = -P_0$

$f(3) = -P_1$

$f(4) = P_0$

ie $f(t)$ describes a parametric circle with period 4 and radius 1.

What is the formula for $f$ in terms of $t$, $P_0$ and $P_1$?

Comment: Hint: The parameterization of a circle in any number of dimensions isn’t fundamentally different from its parameterization in $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: @amd: I think I can construct a 3x2 matrix from $P_0$ and $P_1$ and then multiply that by $(cos(\pi t / 2), sin(\pi t / 2))$

Comment: Sounds good to me.